# How to install GRUB2 on shrunken RAID1 disks?

Tags: grub2, mdadm, raid1

**TL;DR:**
Trying to install GRUB2 on block devices that are in RAID1. Stuck at installing bootloader.

#### Goal

to replace HDD-s with smaller SSD-s. Here are the steps that I've taken:

```
# Booted into rescue mode 
# failed and removed the partition from md array
mdadm --manage /dev/md1 -f /dev/sdb2
mdadm --manage /dev/md1 -r /dev/sdb2

# took out the HDD
# shrunk the filesystem and then the md
resize2fs -f /dev/md1 85G
mdadm --grow /dev/md1 -z 88G

# md1 mounted fine, no issues there. Didn't try to mount /dev/sdd2, as it's Linux RAID type
# recreated partitions on SSD as they are on HDD

# added to array
mdadm --add /dev/md1 /dev/sdb2

# waited for the sync to finish.
# recreated partitions on second SSD
# removed remaining HDD once synced, added SSD to array
```

#### `gdisk -l`

```
Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  GPT: present

Disk label type: GPT
#    Start          End    Size          Type
1     2048         6143      2M      Linux fs
2     6144    195371534   93.2G    Linux RAID
```

#### Problem

How to install bootloader on the SSD-s? Errors that I'm facing:

```
grub2-install --directory /mnt/sysimage/boot/grub2/i386-pc /dev/sdd
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub2-install error: cannot open `/mnt/sysimage/boot/grub2/i386-pc/kernel.img': No such file or directory.
```

#### Specs

- CentOS 7
- `mdadm v4.1`
- No LVM

*Edit:* Added `gdisk -l` trimmed output

##### Update #1

After `mount --bind`-ing `/{proc,dev,sys}` and running `grub2-install`, I get following error. Perhaps I've mis-configured something?

```
grub2-install: warning: Couldn't find physical volume `(null)'. Some modules may be missing from core image.. (2x)
grub2-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be psosible.
grub2-install: error: embedding is not possible, but this is rquired for RAID and LVM install.
```

##### Update #2

After consulting [the manual](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB#BIOS_systems) `grub2-install` succeeded!

What I did for posterity's sake:

```
gdisk /dev/sdd
# t - changed partition 1 type to ef02 -- BIOS boot partition
chroot /mnt/sysimage/
grub2-install /dev/sdd
# grub2-install warned about not finding physical volume `(null)' but installation finished without any errors.
# added to md, failed, removed the other disk, repeated grub2-install
```

Server booted! Thank you for your time and guidance, @telcoM!

Now need to check that everything works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--directory` option defines where `grub2-install` will take the GRUB component files *from*, while `--boot-directory` defines where it'll put them *to*.

It'll be much easier to set up a rescue chroot than to type all the long pathnames required to run `grub2-install` directly from the rescue environment: you might need to specify `--grub-setup`, `--grub-mkrelpath` and `--grub-probe` in addition to `--directory` and `--boot-directory`. So:

```
mount --rbind /dev /mnt/sysimage/dev
mount -t proc none /mnt/sysimage/proc
mount -t sysfs none /mnt/sysimage/sys
chroot /mnt/sysimage /bin/bash
grub2-install /dev/sdd
```

But if you want to do it your way: (`\` marks a line split for readability)

```
grub2-install --directory=/mnt/sysimage/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc \
    --grub-setup=/mnt/sysimage/usr/bin/grub2-setup \
    --grub-mkrelpath=/mnt/sysimage/usr/bin/grub2-mkrelpath \
    --grub-probe=/mnt/sysimage/usr/sbin/grub2-probe \
    --boot-directory=/mnt/sysimage/boot \
    /dev/sdd
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! Tried mounting with bind but unfortunately I'm greeted with warnings and an error (listed in Update #1)

Also added `fdisk` output to the question. It seems I have missed a step or misconfigured something.

Comment: After ̶R̶T̶F̶M̶  adressing the manual, I managed to install GRUB2 on `sdd`.